# How do I fix Sails.js v0.11.1 Grunt errors?

Tags: gruntjs, sails.js

I recently upgraded to Sails v0.11.1 from v0.10.x I am now getting the below `Grunt error occurred` error. Based on research I've tried the following:

- Removed `Gruntfile.js` - this does remove the errors, but of course now I do not have the advantage of all the fancy grunt-contrib modules. Doesn't seem like a good solution for the long run.
- I generated a new Sails project and diffed the the new `Gruntfile.js` and `package.js` with my old ones. The main Gruntfile diff was a reference to `loadNpmTasks` instead of `loadTasks` and on package.js `grunt-contrib` with `~` references rather than `^`. It still produces errors related to Grunt.
- Lastly I moved all `grunt-contrib` references to the `devDependencies`. No dice there too.
- The error also references a `sails-linker:devJs` warning. Not sure how to fix that.

This all seems to be related to the `grunt-contrib` being [DEPRECATED](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib), but haven't found a way to upgrade my project yet to get the full grunt support w/o errors.

Any thoughts?

#### Error

```
error: ** Grunt :: An error occurred. **
error: 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aborted due to warnings.
Running "coffee:dev" (coffee) task
Warning: Task "sails-linker:devJs" not found. 
------------------------------------------------------------------------

error: Looks like a Grunt error occurred--
```

Answer (score 0):

this type of grunt error occurs due to not finding the gem module.

in your case ,its not able to find coffee module so try running following command :

```
> sudo gem install coffee
```

it should work.